# Magento extension: How to output a string on a CMS page or block

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create my first Magento extension and I'm stuck at the first step already.

When adding `{{block type="rick_printer/print" text="Hello world"}}` to a CMS page or block, I want "Hello world" to be displayed.
Unfortunately nothing happens. Here's my code:

**app\code\local\Rick\Printer\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Rick_Printer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Rick_Printer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <rick_printer>
                <class>Rick_Printer_Block_Print</class>
            </rick_printer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app\etc\modules\Rick_Printer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rick_Printer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Rick_Printer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Rick\Printer\Block\Print.php**

```
class Rick_Printer_Block_Print extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{  
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('rick/printer/view.phtml');
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function printIt()
    {
        $text = $this->getText();
        if (!$text) {
            $msg = "Please provide a text!";
            echo $msg;
            return array();
        }        
        return $text;
    }
}
```

**app\design\frontend\default\default\template\rick\printer\print.phtml**

```
<?php
    $text = $this->spinIt();
    echo $text;
?>
```

I know the code is ugly and I'm probably doing it all wrong.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

---

**Update:** After applying the fix from Vinai's answer my **app\code\local\Rick\Printer\etc\config.xml** looks now like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Rick_Printer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Rick_Printer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <rick_printer>
                <class>Rick_Printer_Block</class>
            </rick_printer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and I'm getting the following error message when accessing the CMS page (which doesn't show):

```
class Rick_Printer_Block_Print extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{  
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('rick/printer/view.phtml');  
        parent::_construct();
    }  

    public function printIt()
    {
        $text = $this->getText();  
        if (!$text) {
            $msg = "Please provide a text!";  
            echo $msg; return array();
        }
        return $text;
    }
}


Fatal error: Class 'Rick_Printer_Block_Print' not found in /home/www/xyz/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

Comment: The error message indicates a file system path to class name mismatch. Check for typos and casing. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your block class prefix is wrong. Despite the node name being `<class>`, what you are actually specifying is a **class prefix**.
Another way to look at it is that this node declares the directory, in which the blocks for the module are located.
The correct way is

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<global>
    <blocks>
        <rick_printer>
            <class>Rick_Printer_Block</class>
        </rick_printer>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Second, in your template you are calling `$this->spinIt();` instead of `$this->printIt();`.
Just a typo...

Otherwise the code looks okay.

**UPDATE**
The error message indicates a file system path to class name mismatch. Check the casing and for typos.
Also, since you want your block to render a template, you want to extend `Rick_Printer_Block_Print` from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` instead of the `_Abstract` block class.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get:
    `class Rick_Printer_Block_Print extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {  
     protected function _construct() {  
      $this->setTemplate('rick/printer/view.phtml');  
   parent::_construct(); }  
  public function printIt() {  
  $text = $this->getText();  
  if (!$text){  
      $msg = "Please provide a text!";  
   echo $msg; return array(); }  
  return $text; }  
 }  
 Fatal error: Class 'Rick_Printer_Block_Print' not found in /home/www/xyz/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491`

Comment: This isn't very readable, please update your original post with additional information and then post a short comment here to alert me to the changes.

Comment: I don't get how to properly format a comment. Updated the original post at the bottom. Thanks!